# webpack cannot find node module ('bootstrap-multiselect')

Tags: webpack, bootstrap-multiselect

My webpack config specifies a number of node modules to build into `vendors.js`. All modules are installed with `npm` and reside in a parent folder `node_modules`.

The folder structure:

```
app/scripts/a.js
node_modules/bootstrap-multiselect
webpack.config.js
```

Snippet from webpack.config.js:

```
entry: {
  vendors: ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'bootstrap-multiselect']
}
```

This is fine for 'jquery' and 'bootstrap', but not for 'bootstrap-multiselect':

```
ERROR in multi vendors
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bootstrap-multiselect' 
in /home/user/app
```

It seems as if webpack is looking into the wrong node_modules folder. It looks at the root of the app folder it seems, but then why would it still find the other modules? So I've added every variation of `resolve` and `resolveLoader`,

```
resolveLoader: {root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')};
resolve: {root: [path.join __dirname, 'node_modules']};
```

Still no luck...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why but the `package.json` downloaded with `npm` doesn't seem to be properly configured. The `main` entry points to a non existing file. That's why you are probably getting the error.

### package.json

```
"main": "dist/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
```

The `bootstrap-multiselect.js` file is not under `dist` but `dist/js`. As a workaround you can:

1. Use the full path in your `vendors` field and `require`'s:

   ```
   vendors : ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect']

   require('bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect';
   ```
2. Or, alias the package to the 'real' file in your `webpack.config.js`:

   ```
   resolve: {
     alias: {
       'bootstrap-multiselect': 'bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect'
     }
   }
   ```

However, sooner or later it should be fixed because I checked the github project and there the [`package.json`](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/blob/master/package.json#L5) file looks correct.

Comment: That's it! Excellent and thank you very much for your help. I've notified the author so he can update his package in NPM:

Comment: @BercoBeute Did the maintainer ever reply? The `package.json` is still broken.

Comment: And I thought I was doing something wrong... It's still broken :P